# How to navigate between views in Android Espresso

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso

I am currently learning Espresso, I'm writing a test case where user does the following.

Pre-condition:-
Create a rule to activate a login activity:

1. Opens the app
2. Types username password
3. Clicks on login button

Now user gets redirected to a new activity where it displays the username.
How do I assert the text in Logged in activity?

Basically how to navigate between multiple activities in a single testcase

Comment: What does the first activity do after a successful login? How does it tell the second activity which username to display? Is it sent in the Intent?

Comment: When I perform the action manually, clicking on the login button loads a screen with a search text box. But when I automate this test with Espresso, clicking on the login button doesn't load up the screen with the search text box. Any leads on how I can load the next screen, on button click to log in?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code that executes when the user clicks on the login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by pointing the @Rule notation to the MainActivity class. Previously I had pointed this to a different activity class where it does authentication logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing unit tests, you should test each Activity independently of other Activities. For example, testing the login Activity, should go through the motions of logging in and verify that the login button performs the correct behavior. If it calls `startActivity()` with an Intent, then you should just verify that the correct Intent is sent. This particular task should not worry about which Activity is actually started in the main app. Another test can then verify that the second activity behaves correctly for the Intents that it receives.